# red(), green(), blue() method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I tried hand_gesture_recognition of [Blobscanner](https://code.google.com/p/blobscanner/) in Eclipse.
There's this line to get a red value of a pixel:

```
int  []  Background;  

void Set(PImage I){

    for(int i=0; i<I.width*I.height; i++){
        int iP=I.pixels[i];
        Background[i*3]=(int)red(iP);
    }

}
```

the last line being the reason for this error:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at processing.core.PApplet.red(Unknown Source)  
    at Test$PBGS.Set(Test.java:475)  
    at Test$PBGS.<init>(Test.java:466)  
    at Test.setup(Test.java:39)  
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)  
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm guessing that this is related to the point where if you implement Processing in Eclipse, you've gotta change `color` type to `int`. So, is there any way to change/implement this [red()](http://processing.org/reference/red_.html) method if you want to use Processing in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NullPointerExceptions` shouldn't be the result of a type conversion between `color` and `int`, and in any case `red()` returns a `float`, so your cast should work fine.

I'm assuming you initialized your array, because the stack trace seems to show that the error wasn't caused by that assignment specifically...

Looking at the [Processing source for `PApplet`](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java), I see this definition for `red()`:

```
public final float red(int rgb) {
    return g.red(rgb);
}
```

where `g` is declared as

```
public PGraphics g;
```

Based on my quick scan through the source, it seems that `g` is only initialized in the `init()` method or in the `public void size(final int w, final int h, String renderer, String path)` method.

Looking at your stack trace, it appears that `g` has not been initialized yet. Did you call either `init()` or `size()` anywhere else in your code?

In [PGraphics](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PGraphics.java):

```
public final float red(int rgb) {
    float c = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
    if (colorModeDefault) return c;
    return (c / 255.0f) * colorModeX;
}
```

So nothing there could throw a `NullPointerException`, as it's all math. My first guess is that the `PGraphics` object that `red()` needs was never initialized.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answer! I found that changing "(int)red(iP)" into "iP >> 16 & 0xFF" pass me through that error... only pass, whether it works or not I don't know, because now the error moves to the same problem, but with the brightness() method...

Comment: Well, because you removed the method call and replaced it with just math, it makes sense that you no longer get a `NullPointerException`, because you removed the method call that caused the issue.

Comment: Again, did you call `init()` or `size()` anywhere in your code? If you made those calls `red()` should no longer throw a `NullPointerException` because the `PGraphics` object that that method needs will no longer be `null`

Comment: Source code tells me that you have the exact same issue in the `brightness()` method. The `PGraphics` object was never initialized.

Comment: Wenggg thank you so much it works! I put `init` in `FingerDetector` constructor and it works! Waaah thank you so much sir! ^^